# Getting MODULE_NOT_FOUND when using package.json subpath exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules, npm-workspaces

I'm trying to understand how to use [Subpath exports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-exports) but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Using node v17.6.0 (64-bit) + windows10 and I've created a simple project to play around that looks like this:

```
│   package.json                          
│                                         
├───packages                              
│   └───myorg-common                      
│       │   index.js                      
│       │   package.json                  
│       │                                 
│       └───src                           
│           │   a.js                      
│           │   index.js                  
│           │                             
│           └───b                         
│                   b.js                  
│                                         
└───src                                   
    │   main.js                           
    │                                     
    └───c                                 
            c.js                          
            index.js
```

## ROOT

**.\package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test_exports",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "esm": "^3.2.25"
  }
}
```

**.\src\main.js**

```
import * as modroot from "@myorg/common/module_root";
// import * as moda from "@myorg/common/module_a";
// import * as modb from "@myorg/common/module_b";

console.log(modroot);
// console.log(moda);
// console.log(modb);
```

**.\src\c\c.js**

```
export const C="src/c/c.js";
```

**.\src\c\index.js**

```
export * from "./c";
```

## WORKSPACE

**.\packages\myorg-common\index.js**

```
export const ROOT="ROOT";
```

**.\packages\myorg-common\package.json**

```
{
  "name": "@myorg/common",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "exports": {
    "./module_root": "./src/index.js",
    "./module_a": "./src/a.js",
    "./module_b": "./src/b/b.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**.\packages\myorg-common\src\a.js**

```
export const A="src/a.js";
```

**.\packages\myorg-common\src\index.js**

```
export * from "./a";
export * from "./b/b";
```

**.\packages\myorg-common\src\b\b.js**

```
export const B="src/b/b.js";
```

## QUESTION

After doing `npm install` in the root path and running `node -r esm src\main.js` I'll get this error:

```
D:\test_exports\node_modules\esm\esm.js:1
const __global__ = this;(funct ...TRUNCATED_CONTENT_OR_I_WON'T_BE_ABLE_TO_SUBMIT_TO_SO... default=Jh})]).default;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

D:\test_exports\src\main.js:1
Error: Cannot find module '@myorg/common/module_root'
Require stack:
- D:\test_exports\src\main.js
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\test_exports\src\main.js:1) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'D:\\test_exports\\src\\main.js' ]
}

Node.js v17.6.0
```

Couple of questions:

- Why am I getting that MODULE_NOT_FOUND error and how to fix it? My main goal is being able to learn how to export all subpackages from my workspaces without having to bundle them (ie: it'd be great to use src content directly from my CRA apps that are using webpack through react-scripts).
- That huge dump coming from [esm](https://github.com/standard-things/esm), is there any way to avoid all that noise/log? In older versions of node I don't remember the output was so verbose.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [esm](https://github.com/standard-things/esm) is the culprit here and I'm not sure about how to "fix" it. Nonetheless, everything will work fine with webpack/rollup/vite etc. (tested).

To make it work with node, you'd have to either use `commonjs` to avoid using [esm](https://github.com/standard-things/esm) or just switch to ES modules by changing your file extensions to `.mjs` or by adding `"type": "module"` in your `package.json` and then run:

```
node src/main.mjs
```

or

```
node src/main.js
```

depending on what you decided to go with.

NOTE: if you choose to use ES modules with node, you'd have to add the file extensions to your import/export statements in both cases. e.g.: `export * from './a.js'` or `export * from '.a.mjs'`